# Different labels for subsection titles and references

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering

I am constructing my thesis, and am using a variant of the report class. I have chapters, sections, subsections, and subsubsections in places. When reading the text, having a long string of numbers, letters, and roman numerals in the title for subsections and subsubsections is unpleasant-looking. I would prefer these titles to just have the relevant subsection or subsubsection title, and do so using:

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Roman{subsection}}
```

(Depending on how things end up looking, I may include the section counter, but I'll definitely strip off the chapter counter.) However, when I make a reference to the subsection or subsubsection, I would much prefer the entire string of numbers to be used, otherwise the reference is poorly defined. Can anyone comment on how to do this?

Here is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Roman{subsection}}

\chapter{Chapter}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}\label{subsection}

\noindent I have the subsections labelled in Roman in the title, because 1.1.I would just be long.
\\

\noindent Here is a reference to the subsection: (\ref{subsection})
\\

\noindent I would like references to the subsection to be (1.1.I), however.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Redefine `\p@subsection` (the prefix using for the references to subsections):

```
\documentclass{report}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Roman{subsection}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@subsection{\thesection.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}\label{subsection}

\noindent I have the subsections labelled in Roman in the title, because 1.1.I would just be long.

\noindent Here is a reference to the subsection: (\ref{subsection})

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, never use the combination `\\ + blank line`; this will generate underfull boxes warnings.

Comment: Wow, that was incredibly fast. Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 5):

References can automatically be prefixed by `\p@<counter>`, see example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{parskip}

\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\Roman{subsection}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\p@subsection}{\thesection.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}

Here is a reference to the subsection: \ref{subsection}

\section{Section}

\subsection{Subsection}\label{subsection}

\end{document}
```

Result:

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you. Basically the same answer as above, and works a charm :-) Does the * in renewcommand* do anything significant?

Comment: Yes, written at the same time. `\(re)newcommand` with star is the same as `\def`, without star it is `\long\def`. Here the difference is not important (without arguments).