# Include section number in reference to subsection

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

In an article I omit the section number for subsection titles, using:

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
```

However, when I now create a `\label` in a subsection and reference it using `\ref` in another part of the document, the printed reference only shows the subsection number, even in a totally different section! How can I show the section AND subsection number in references (as usual) while keeping only the subsection number in subsection titles?

MCVE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\section{My first section}

\subsection{Foo}

\subsection{Bar}
\label{ssec:bar}

\section{My second section}

\subsection{Misc}

\subsection{Notes}

See also subsection \ref{ssec:bar}.

\end{document}
```

The printed reference shows `2`, however, I want it to be `1.2`.

Comment: remove `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}`. than will work as desired.

Comment: @Zarko then the subsection title will also contain the section number, which I don't want

Comment: than you can't expect desired numbering in references. reference always reproduce number of section.

Comment: Try `\makeatletter\renewcommand\p@subsection{\thesection.}\makeatother`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/186974/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67742/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/437402/35864

Comment: Thanks @moewe, that was exactly what I was looking for. I marked the question as duplicate